# Please help, this loop isn't working as expected and I don't know how to use booleans in Python

Tags: python

Am trying to write a piece of python code that calculate and print 1000 prime number from 2
however i only got 1999 as the last element in my result. I know there a lot of questions like this asked before but I wanna know why is my code is not working.
btw: how do i declare a boolean value in python? cant find a clue even googled···sad

```
mylist=[2]
num=1
count=0
while count<1000:
    if num>1:
        add=1
        for i in mylist:
            if num%i==0:
                add=0
                break
        if add==1:
            mylist=mylist+[num]
    num=num+2
    count=count+1
print mylist
```

Comment: These are your hints. These are your hints on Python. Any questions?

Comment: "how do i declare a boolean value in python?" - by typing that sentence into google: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: I updated my answer with two examples in idiomatic Python. One simply uses bool and only requires knowledge of constructs of which you're already aware (or should be aware, given that you're using lists). The other requires some knowledge of the workings of iterators and iterator comprehensions to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should read `while len(mylist) < 1000:`, and remove all references to `count`. Either that, or you should only increment `count` every time you add a prime to the list.

Also, you don't 'declare' values in Python. You simply assign a value of the desired type to a variable, and poof, you have a variable of that type. In this case, `True` and `False` are boolean values and you can assign them to variables.

Here is my version in idiomatic (i.e. written the way an experienced Python programmer might write it) Python:

```
primes = [2]
candidate = 3
while len(primes) < 1000:
    isprime = True
    for testprime in primes:
        if candidate % testprime == 0:
            isprime = False
            break
    if isprime:
        primes.append(candidate)
    candidate = candidate + 2
print primes
```

If you want to write it in even terser and faster Python, do this:

```
import itertools
primes = [2]
candidate_iter = itertools.count(3, 2)
while len(primes) < 1000:
    candidate = candidate_iter.next()
    if all(candidate % testprime != 0 for testprime in primes):
        primes.append(candidate)
print primes
```

Comment: @beautCode: Oh, oops. *sheepish grin* Fixed that. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious: that isn't completely idiomatic Python. Idiomatic Python would throw away the `isprime = True` and `isprime = False` lines and change `if isprime:` to `else:` (probably `else:  # prime`). And it would change `candidate = candidate + 2` to `candidate += 2`.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Perhaps some would. I have never seen that construct before, and I don't like it now that I have. I do agree about the `+=`, but I didn't want to introduce many new things to the OP as it's clear that the OP is learning.

Comment: `for..else` blocks can improve some sorts of code a lot. First time you see one you'll wonder quite what's going on, but it's a nice construct, really. This is an example of a case which is improved by using it (as @agf has in his answer).

Comment: @Chris Morgan: In fact, it's the wrong construct to use here. The right construct, which is faster, clearer, and shorter, is to use `all`.

Comment: @Omnifarous: well, yeah. Now you've put your shorter version in, you get my vote. That's definitely a better way to do it. Though personally I think `candidate = 3` and `candidate += 2` after the `if` is nicer than using `itertools.count`, and it's a tad faster too (as it should be). And you can also drop the `!= 0` if you want.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: By my tests, there is no real difference. The itertools version seems (in fact) to be very slight faster by about 1 or 2%.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Python, it's good to learn the Python idioms. I've used several below, including `itertools.count`, using `not` to test if something is equal to zero, `else` clauses on loops, and negative indexing to get the last item of a list.

Also, the Python standard is to use four-space indentation, as below; spaces around operators like `=`, `==`, and `%`; and spaces after commas.

```
from itertools import count
mylist = [2]
# This will go up by 2s starting from 3: 3, 5, 7, 9...
for num in count(3, 2):
    # For each prime already found
    for i in mylist:
        # if the prime is a factor of the number
        if not num % i:
            # don't add it
            break
    else:
        # if none of the primes were factors
        # add this number to the list of primes
        mylist.append(num)
        # if there are 1000 numbers in the list, we're done
        if len(mylist) == 1000:
            break
# print the 1000th prime
print mylist[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're incrementing the variable `count` for each number in the set 1,3,5,...,2001. Instead you should increment the `count` only when `add == 1`

Here's the same as code for the later generations:

```
primes = [2]                              # initial list of primes 
candidate = 1                             # let's start at 1, could start at 3 as well
primesFound = 1                           # We've actually found one already
while primesFound <= 1000:                # continue till 1000 primes have been found
                                          # using a counter instead of len(primes) 
                                          # maybe faster
    if candidate > 1:                     # 1 is not a prime
        isPrime = True                    
        for i in primes:                  # iterate over all primes already found 
            if candidate % i == 0:        # primes should not be divisable
                isPrime = False           # not a prime
                break                     # no use going through the rest of the primes
        if isPrime:                       # candidate is a prime so
            primes = primes + [candidate] # add it to the primes list
            primesFound += 1              # increment the prime counter
    candidate += 2                        # we can skip all even numbers 
print primes                              # done.
```